# Passing down to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two component. One parent called menu and one called food. So in menu I have this one line of code that is:

```
{this.props.menu ? Object.keys(this.props.menu).map((key, index) => 
    <div
      className="tab-pane fade"
      id={key}
      role="tabpanel"
      aria-labelledby={key + "-tab"}
    >
      <Food key={key} menu={this.props.menu}/>
    </div>
  ) : 'loading'
}
```

So I'm trying to pass down "key" to food and use in this line of code like this:

```
{this.props.menu? this.props.menu[key].map((d) => <h1>{d.name}</h1>) : 'loading'}'
```

However, I keep getting key not defined. I never pass something like this before down to the child component so not sure if I'm just passing it wrong or something else.

Comment: React keys, and refs, are not props. You'll need to pass this value to `Food` as another named prop.

Answer (score 0):

`key` is a reserved property in react. The framework handles it and removes it from the props collection. Therefore it is undefined when you try to access it with `props.key`.
As @Drew Reese commented you better use just a different prop name.

Answer (score -1):

It may be issue that you have not defined the value of key.

Object.keys(this.props.menu) -> it will give you an array of the key of an object.

example obj = {"a": 1, "b":2}.
Object.keys(obj) --> ["a","b"]

then you are using map on array. It will loop over each element of the array.
Object.keys(obj).map( (key,index) => { } ) ==>. key is item of array and index is position of the item in array.

Key is used when we are looping over repeated item in react.

```
{this.props.menu? this.props.menu.map((d) => <h1 key={d.name}>{d.name}</h1>) : 'loading'}'
```